# Avoid SSL warning when certificate is issued for root domain only

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I am having the following issue, trying to set up the SSL certificate. 
When opening the root domain name `example.com` the browser shows the green sign and all is fine. However trying to open with www version `www.example.com` I see the following message

> www.example.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for example.com
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

From this message I am guessing that the SSL was issued for example.com only (please correct me if Im wrong), now except buying another certificate, that would include both versions, is there another way to avoid that warning, namely kind of to redirect all traffic to `example.com` before even "showing" to the browser the certificate ? So, when the user types `https://www.example.com` it would redirect to `https://example.com`, where the certificate is already valid.

I have this in my site file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /home/username/www/example

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to put a redirect condition inside VH, however it did not help.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Apache 2.2.22, Debian 7.9

Thanks

Comment: Have the certificate reissued. They should have added www.example.com to it to begin with.

Comment: If there were such a way, that would be a huge security hole. A person who punches `https://www.domain.com/` into their browser should either get something that can prove it's `www.domain.com` or it should get a security error. they should definitely *not* get some other site without a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The TLS protocol (and its obsolete predecessor, SSL) validates the certificate according to the host part of the URL, in this case the complete domain name, before any data is transferred.  This is by design, and fulfils several security requirements.

You should get a certificate (it's not called "an SSL") issued for both your domain names; the feature used to do this is called subjectAlternativeName or SAN.  Sometimes you can also get a wildcard certificate that includes both `*.example.com` and `example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

First off, most certificates should come with www already. I haven't heard of one that only is issued for the root domain. TLS actually checks the entire URL, not just the root domain, so a certificate for the root, without WWW, will be invalid if used on a WWW domain. Wildcard and EV certificates also exist, but those are much more expensive.

As to SSL certificates, have you considered using Let's Encrypt instead of buying the certificate outright? Let's Encrypt allows you to issue multiple certificates for any number of subdomains (up to 100) for free.

Comment: Hopefully nobody is issuing certificates for TLDs, since that refers to like `com`.