# Generate CSR considering root domain and www version

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I have purchased a SSL certificate (NOT wildcard), that as I found out was issued for `example.com` only and did not include the `www` version so I was getting warning, as I posted in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/746399/avoid-ssl-warning-when-certificate-is-issued-for-root-domain-only) when typing the www version from address bar.

I contacted their support with that question and was told that I had to include the www version when generating the `csr`.

When I am generating CSR I use these commands

```
openssl genrsa -out example.com.key 2048

openssl req -new -key example.com.key -out example.com.csr
```

During the last command I am putting `example.com` for Comman Name. So, how to include the www version as well.

**EDIT:** CA is RapidSSL.

**UPDATE:**
When I contacted their support for cancellation, found out that I had to put www.example.com and in that case the non-www version would be considered automatically, so I re-generated with the CSR putting Common name as `www.example.com` and it works fine now.

Thanks

Comment: Some (like godaddy) include www. Automatically as a subject alternative name, sorry about your luck with rapid

Comment: Your answer to include the SAN for www. Is http://security.stackexchange.com/a/91556/84379

Comment: @JacobEvans, thanks for the link, it turned out I had to put `www.example.com` - please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this page](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO13985&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US):

> RapidSSL certificates can only be used on Web servers using the Common
>   Name specified during enrollment. For example, a certificate for the
>   domain "domain.com" will receive a warning if accessing a site named
>   "www.domain.com" or "secure.domain.com", because "www.domain.com" and
>   "secure.domain.com" are different from "domain.com".

---

If you need to use both domains, unfortunately your only option is to use another SSL certificate authority, as RapidSSL does not allow you to add both the `example.com` and `www.example.com` domains to the same certificate.

You *can* generate a CSR with multiple Common Name fields, however it requires a bit of playing with your OpenSSL configuration - which in all honesty, shouldn't be necessary. Documentation is [here](https://certificates.heanet.ie/node/17).

Most CAs (including [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/) which issue single-domain certificates for free, and also the [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) open-source CA which is still in public beta) will automatically add the blank domain to any issued certificate.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the CA is RapidSSL, are you aware if they do so, I mean if I re-generate the CSR with `www.example.com` will they consider the non-www version as well ? thanks

Comment: @dav my apologies, seems RapidSSL do not offer this. I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I guess the redirect is not a solution, because as I found out from my this question http://serverfault.com/questions/746399/avoid-ssl-warning-when-certificate-is-issued-for-root-domain-only, it does not work, I can still see the warning when accessing through www (like https://www.example.com), that is why I wanted to generate the CSR for both www and non-www, so I can re-issue the certificate. thanks

Comment: The only solution in this case if you need to use both domains is to change your SSL CA.

Comment: hmm, but the support member told me that I just had to include both www and non-www versions when generating CSR, so is it impossible ? thanks

Comment: Personally, I would find another CA regardless - most CAs will automatically add the non-www domain when generating a certificate for any subdomain to stop this exact issue. You *can* generate a CSR with multiple CNs but it's not for the faint-hearted - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I contacted their support for cancellation and found out that I had to put `www.example.com` and in that case the non-www version would be considered automatically, which as I tried out was correct. Thank you

Comment: Sounds like the opposite of what's typical, good to know